# Where can I ask for a translation?

Tags: discussion

I tried to find what I was looking for elsewhere. That led me to this site. I saw a question similar to my own in the history section. I asked there. I got chewed out for it. I searched for someplace more suitable to ask. I found this. I learned that translation requests are not acceptable here. I tried to find another Stack Exchange site that might be more suitable, but found none (at least none that were obvious). Since this is a question about the site, I tried to go to the meta to ask where I might find this mythical El Dorado where I might finally be allowed to ask for a translation, but as it turns out, one needs a certain reputation to ask questions in the meta, which I don't have. That leaves me with no choice but to ask here: where can I go to ask for a translation? Should I just go to Reddit instead?

Comment: https://reddit.com/r/translator . https://www.fiverr.com/ . maybe the SE for your specific language, if there's one and the rules allow it. p.s. when you're looking for professional services for free, you should at least try to be polite about it.

Comment: Thank you for being constructive. On the latter part of your comment: I wasn't exactly treated very well myself. Nothing really struck me as "professional" about what I've seen here so far.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, translation request on Stack Exchange is discouraged due to its nature of a Q&A site with the goal *to help future readers, in addition to the asker*. Thus, we prefer to have questions that may expose concepts that can give more insights than just a straight-up translation, which many of "please translate this" requests don't.

That aside, some foreign language SE sites *do* accept translation request within a boundary:

- Chinese Language: [What translation questions are on topic for this site?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/what-translation-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site)
- Esperanto Language: [Are questions asking the translation of a complex sentence acceptable?](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/are-questions-asking-the-translation-of-a-complex-sentence-acceptable)
- French Language: [Translation questions — Questions de traduction](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions-questions-de-traduction)
- German Language: [Does my translation request belong here and if not, where and how shall I ask it?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/does-my-translation-request-belong-here-and-if-not-where-and-how-shall-i-ask-it)
- Italian Language: [Are questions about translation requests on topic?](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic)
- Japanese Language: [Should pure translation questions be allowed?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/should-pure-translation-questions-be-allowed)
- Korean Language: [What is the policy for translation requests?](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-policy-for-translation-requests)
- Latin Language: [What do we do with translation requests?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-do-we-do-with-translation-requests)
- Portuguese Language: [Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Portuguese on topic here?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/is-asking-to-translate-a-short-paragraph-from-english-to-portuguese-on-topic-her)
- Russian Language: [Would this translation question be welcome?](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/would-this-translation-question-be-welcome)
- Spanish Language: [Should this “translation” question be accepted as-is, or split up?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/should-this-translation-question-be-accepted-as-is-or-split-up)
- Ukrainian Language: [Questions tagged with 'from-*' (language source)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from-*)

Aside from these languages, unfortunately there's no one-for-all translation SE site. In that case, the only alternative is to look for external sites like Reddit, etc.